# Using multiple htaccess file in directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, webserver

I am beginner in .htaccess file configuration.I use xampp technology and I test my project in localhost.
In my project when i type localhost in url , url should rewrite to localhost/test/test1 but address bar should not change.
in htdocs folder I created sub directory (test) and another sub directory (test1) inside (test). I created one .htaccess file on htdocs and one another on (test) directory.

.htaccess on htdocs folder:

```
Options -Indexes 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} . [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^test(.*)$ test/$1 [N]
```

.htaccess on test folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} . [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
#RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test1/$1 [L]
```

in test 1 i have index.php file:

```php
<?php
echo "we are in test/test1 directory!!!";
```

When I type localhost in url I got this error:

Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500
localhost
Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1b PHP/7.3.4

Comment: Stop relying on such dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"), they are a bad idea in most cases since they come with a ton of disadvantages over using the real http server's host configuration. They are only offered as a last alternative for those without any access to the real configuration (read: really cheap hosting providers).

Comment: Thanks for response. But I do not have any access to real configuration file and I need to set configuration by .htaccess .